# SpecFlow Feature File not recognising all lines

Tags: specflow

SpecFlow Feature file has around 40 scenarios many a times few of the scenarios are not recognized even if they have binding methods. Feature file looks fine after giving 1/2 back spaces and this is happening often. Any suggestions ?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on the feature file and go to the definition are they referencing more than one step? When you have duplication, you will see this happen.

ex:

```
And I click |Submit|

And I click |Continue|
```

This produces the below which matches both of the above and your feature file steps will not be found.

```
    [Then(@"I click \|(.*)\|")]
    public void ThenIClickSubmit(string value)
    {
        ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
    }
```

The one suggestion I tell people is this. Make sure each of your steps is unique. Your steps are constantly being added sothey can be difficult to find. Try to reference the page the action is on. This will help you find the step from the intellisense drop down easily and also and help make the step unique.

```
And I click |Submit| on the Password Reset Page 

When I click |Link1| in the Header Menu
```